# getting actionlist to send current url to actionresult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass my current url to my actionresult but returnUrl always comes up  null

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Create Student", "Create", "StudentCenter", new{ returnUrl = Request.RawUrl}, new { @class = "button" })
```

here's the controller

```
public ActionResult Create(string returnUrl)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("redirectCookie",returnUrl);
        ViewBag.Sex = new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(SchoolCup.Domain.Sex)));
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What is the URL that is being generated?

Comment: teamcenter/addstudent

Comment: That doesn't match the code that you posted.  The code that you posted would go to the `StudentCenter` controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Student", "Create", "StudentCenter", new{ returnUrl = Request.RawUrl.ToString()}, new { @class = "button" })
```

Please try and send me a feed back

Is your expected string like this "studentCenter/create"?